# Transferencia de dinero entre cuentas de MercadoPago

Tags: mercadopago

Quisiera saber si es factible realizar una transferencia de dinero entre cuentas de MercadoPago utilizando la API.

Según veo en [la documentación oficial de MercadoPago](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/api-docs/custom-checkout/create-payments/), entiendo que esto puede ser realizado por medio de la creación de un Payment, especificando el `operation_type` como `money_transfer`.

Mi duda respecto de esto es como puedo yo crear un pago hacia otro usuario, siendo yo el `payer`. ¿Es esto factible? Se que se puede usar el `collector_id` para identificar al vendedor, pero ¿el `collector_id` hace referencia a un customer o a un usuario de MercadoPago?

Comment: Revisaste la sección "Solicitudes de Dinero"? https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/money-requests/

Comment: Este curso te será de utilidad: https://www.acamica.com/cursos/105/la-api-mercadolibre-conceptos-finales y este otro también! https://www.acamica.com/cursos/62/introduccion-a-la-api-de-mercadolibre Saludos :D

Answer (score 0):

En MercadoPago existe un producto para la solicitud de dinero entre 2 personas:

https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/payments/api/money-transfer

Via API se llamaria de la siguiente manera:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
'https://api.mercadopago.com/money_requests?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN' \
-d '{
    "currency_id" : "ARS",
    "payer_email" : "payer@email.com",
    "amount" : 2.1,
    "description" : "Description",
    "concept_type" : "off_platform"
}'
```

Donde el ACCESS_TOKEN corresponde a las credenciales del usuario receptor del pago.

> Otro escenario es el de **Marketplace**, en el que permitimos que un
>   usuario pueda autorizar a otro a solicitar pagos en su nombre útil
>   para tiendas con múltiples vendedores o modelos p2p.

https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/marketplace/web-checkout/introduction/

Esta basado en oAuth2 para la autenticación.

Adicionalmente te permite cobrar una comisión por la transacción como intermediario de ser necesario.

Comment: Marketplace se puede usar en conjunto con el SDK de Android/IOS? Mi aplicación es mobile only.

Comment: Via API siempre es posible, seria de forma manual mas que usando el SDK

Comment: Se podría utilizar el SDK de Android/IOS, no? O seria todo via web? Puedo generar una preferencia con los datos obtenidos via MarketPlace, y disparar el checkout en Mobile usando los SDKs?

Comment: Seria via API, haciendo los API calls desde tu aplicación android/iOS, en la que deberías construir la UI manualmente.

Comment: Okey! Gracias por tu respuesta!